# Curl request timing out - how to determine if it's on the origin server or the request server?

Tags: php, apache, curl

I'm making curl requests to a SOAP server and I'm getting sporadic timeouts from the server. How can I determine if this is a limitation of the number of concurrent requests from my server, or if it's the server I'm making a request to?

PS - the curl timeout I specified is 60 seconds and it's been working consistently up until about a week ago, and while we have made changes to one of the applications using this, there are other applications which have broken and have not had any updates made on them for awhile.

At the moment I'm implementing failure tracking so I can see the http response codes, timestamps, and relevant variables in the requests but if anyone has any suggestions from past similar incidents I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To see all of what is going on, fire up [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on your server, or some other packet sniffing utility.  Then, you can see which connections are causing you troubles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply telnetting to the server and pasting the request in and seeing what the response comes back like.

Comment: Do you mind linking or providing a code snippet? I've never telnetted before.

Comment: ...unless you do it a bunch of times and a sporadic delay occurs. Maybe it's not obvious that this is tedious but if you do it enough, it will show you if there's a problem or delay in just connecting to the server, if you get one of those "connected..." responses from telnet. It's a simple first step to try.

Comment: From a shell prompt just telnet <serverhostname> 80 (assuming your doing soap over http).  When you run telnet it tries to connect to the server you specify. Http servers don't send back a response upon connection which isn't helpful, but what is helpful is that the telnet program will say "Connected to..." when it is able to establish a TCP connection to the webserver. If you see a [sporadic] delay when doing this, then you've got a network problem, and is has nothing to do with soap or http.